# Spring MVC with Embedded Jetty static resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, embedded-jetty, static-resource

I am using Embedded Jetty:

```
 ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
 JettyHttpThreadPool jettyHttpThreadPool = new JettyHttpThreadPool(serviceName);
 server.setHandler(context);
 server.start();
```

My spring context xml file is:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="mapper"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<mvc:resources mapping="css/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="images/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="lib/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.js" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>

<bean id="mapper" class="com.rest.utils.ObjectMapperFactory"/>

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.rest"/>
```

When I try to get `http://localhost:8080/index.html` I get 404 http status code.

What I am doing wrong? Why can't I get the static resource?

Comment: Do you have index.html file under resources folder?

Comment: Yes I have it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the mapping of the other servlet it should be "/" ans not "/*"